# WPF Brush Import/Export

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, user-interface

I was wondering if there any standard format to import/export brushes in .net.
For example importing a Photoshop brush to a WPF application brush.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

You can [move files into Expression Blend](http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/eyesofblend/import/) which supports WPF and then transform them into controls but you can not move static brush resources from Photoshop into Expression Blend and/or a WPF application within Visual Studio.